# Rails relationships don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, entity-relationship

I'm using Rails 3.0.1/Ruby 1.9.2

I have two tables: `Product` and `Category`.

These are the models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent_category, :class_name => "Category"
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end
```

So I want to access the category of the product by calling `product.parent_category`, and get all products from a certain category by calling `category.products`.

But this doesn't work.

Rails raises an exception when I do `category.products`

```
column products.category_id does not exist
```

It tries to find the `category_id` column, but I have a `parent_category_id` column in my table and I want to use it.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Shouldn't the category model "have_many :products"?

Comment: @Nate, you're right. That's a typo. Fixed.

Comment: And I had a typo in my comment. Ha! "has_many :products"

Comment: why don't you just use "belongs_to :category". instead of "belongs_to :parent_category, :class_name => "Category" "

Comment: @Saran, that's a good point. It's kind of like an experiment. I want to see if I can use defined names for relations. It's definitely not needed here, but it might be useful later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent_category, :class_name => "Category"
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, :foreign_key => :parent_category_id
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent_category, :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => "parent_category_id"
end
```